# Calling a function without a button having problems rendering React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am creating a weather app that implements a toggle button to show the forecast. I tried passing it as a parameter and that did not work.

Next, I attempted the useEffect but it calls the API before there is a value. and throws an error.

ThreeDayForecast

```
const ThreeDayForecast = ( cityName ) => {
    
 //I used Linked to import the cityName from the original input

  let api_key = xxx

//without the useEffect DisplayForecast does not get called
  const displayForecast = async(cityName) => {
    console.log({ cityName })
    console.log("testing")

    if(cityName ==="") {
        

       cityName = "London"
    }

    let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${cityName}&units=Imperial&appid=${api_key}`

  

  let response = await fetch(url)
  let data = await response.json()
//some code
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    displayForecast();
  })
  return (
      // some code
    
  )
}
```

ForecastButton

```
   function toggle() {
    setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen)
      
  }
   
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {label}{" "}
      <div className="toggle-switch">
        
        <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" 
               name={label} id={label} onClick={toggle} />
                
               
        <label className="label" htmlFor={label}>
          <span className="inner" />
          <span className="switch" />
        </label>
        <div style={{ display: isOpen ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
                  
                  <ThreeDayForecast  />
                 </div>
```

Without the useEffect I am unable to call displayForecast, and with it, it gets called too early. I am doing it this way because with the openweatherapi it has either the current weather which has highs and lows.

Or it has the forecast which does not give accurate highs and lows and also doesn't have humidity and such.

Right now I put in the if statement to try and get a placeholder so it does not give the error. But that did not work. I am able to console.log(cityName) with the correct value displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ThreeDayForecast component, you need to pass the cityName as a prop rather than as a parameter. React components receive props as an object parameter, not individual parameters,

```js
const ThreeDayForecast = (cityName) => { // not this
const ThreeDayForecast = ({ cityName }) => { // try this instead
```

You are using useEffect without specifying a dependency array. This means that the effect will run on every render. To avoid this, you should specify cityName as a dependency in the dependency array to ensure that displayForecast is only called when cityName changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 displayForecast(cityName) // Pass the cityName as a parameter
}, [cityName]) // Add cityName to the dependency array
```

Ensure that you have defined and initialized isOpen using the useState hook in your ForecastButton component.

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
```

Make sure you pass the cityName to the ThreeDayForecast component when rendering it inside the ForecastButton

```js
<ThreeDayForecast cityName={cityName} />
```

Comment: So I am getting cityName from a third class that is not listed. In order for me to pass it, I used react-router-dom Link to pass it and it gets passed. Everything I did trying to pass cityName as a parameter did not pass it. I made your adjustments but am still receiving an error stating that the API request is bad before I am able to input the city name. Should I have a placeholder city and then use a setCity state that  is passed into the useEffect, then when the dependency cityName is changed it will update the cityName?

Comment: Do you mean in this line, <ThreeDayForecast cityName={cityName} />, you are receiving the city name from url? if yes then, the answer is yes. you can create a useEffect to set a state and pass it down as cityName prop. Also, you can conditionally render ThreeDayForecast component only when the state is set.

Comment: No i am sending the cityName from a different file 

WeatherApp

```
const sendValue = () => {
            return(
                <div>
                    <Link to="/ForecastButton" cityName={ { cityInput } } />
                </div>
            )
        }

```

Comment: sorry you lost me. I don't think i can help you with the information at hand, because there seems to be multiple components involved. you can either add all components code with your question or a better option would be to create a  [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) with your code. It will be much easier for you to get help this way.

Comment: I made a mistake earlier in my code and was not calling the parameter correctly. Once I noticed my error. I was able to fix my issues with your solution. Thank you